# Class "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Quotes" not found

Tags: laravel-8

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

 

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Mail\SendMail;

use App\Models\Configure;

use App\Models\Qoutes;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 

class QoutesController extends Controller

{

    public function index()

    {

        $page_title = 'Qoutes Manager';

        $qoutes = Quotes::all();

        return view('admin.qoutes.index', compact('page_title', 'qoutes'));

    }

 

 

    public function remove(Request $request)

    {

        $rules = [

            'qoutes' => "required|integer"

        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        }

        $qoutes = Qoutes::findOrFail($request->qoutes);

        $qoutes->delete();
```

Hello, Please help me sort the above error

Comment: Typo: `use App\Models\Qoutes;` vs `Quotes::all();`.  Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflicting class name:

```
$qoutes = Quotes::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled Quotes in the use statement:

```
use App\Models\Qoutes;
```

You also seem to have two 'Quotes' classes. Use `as` to separate them:

```
use App\Models\Quotes as QuotesModel;
```